# Wpresidence - Member info not showing on the property listing page that he submitted

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I use wpresidence (wordpress) and have membership packages, earlier when i submitted a property thorugh the member profile and when i opened the property at the bottom of the page there was a field that was showing who submitted it, but now when i checked again it doesn't show.
To be precise i dont have agents assigned but it should appear on the property listing page which member submitted it, so the customers have an idea who owns the property.
What is the problem? Thanks in advance

I didn't change anything in the settings, the Agent field is visible in wpresidence options but i  think its not connected with the member who submitted the property to be shown on its property listing page.